# McGraw air compressor won't turn on

Tags: troubleshooting, air-compressor

I've got a 14 month old [MCGRAW 8 gallon 1.5 HP 150 PSI Oil-Free Portable Air Compressor](https://www.harborfreight.com/8-gallon-15-hp-150-psi-oil-free-portable-air-compressor-64294.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=12236736217&campaignid=12236736217&utm_content=118873746122&adsetid=118873746122&product=64294&store=2953&gclid=Cj0KCQjwtO-kBhDIARIsAL6LorcOcsJt8KWElbIrCe1ZY-q5_A-k9ESRpkDazR2mopDJoPH86wO2IaAaApjDEALw_wcB) that won't turn on when I plug it in. No sounds at all, not even a click.

One youtube suggestion was that the wiring connectors can come loose so I checked all those that I could find(yellow arrows below).

Any other thoughts of what the issue could be?

[image: w]

Comment: I assume you have checked for power at the outlet.  Have you checked the function of the switch, both the on/off and pressure switches?

Comment: 14 months. So, it had a 90 day or perhaps one year warranty and noticed it was past due to expire, so it saluted and died?

Comment: 1) Contact the manufacturer for troubleshooting solutions. Maybe search the internet for the owners manual - there's usually a basic troubleshooting section in the back. 2) Look for a fuse or breaker that's tripped. There may be some sort of thermal overload protection that needs to be reset/replaced.

Comment: Make sure the pressure sensor switch is operating correctly. Do continuity checks on the circuit to  try to find anything broken, disconnected, or burned out,  Try rotating the motor by hand to make sure it and the pump aren't seized. There's nothing very special about the basic mechanism; it's just a motorized electromechanical device

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes forget and put mine up with pressure in the tank. Then it won't start until I use it and the pressure drops. –

Answer (score 0):

Your gauges are showing pressure in the tank. Assuming they still work,  Let some air out and turn it on again. If still nothing, check the pressure switch. With tank empty, check for continuity across the 2 terminals. If no continuity, replace switch.